# Custom mat-radio-group in Angular 12 not working?

Tags: angular-material, angular12

I have problem when custom using mat-radio-group and mat-radio-button in Angular 12.

I have my-radio-group that wrap mat-radio-group and some my-radio-button as the ContentChildrens,
my-radio-button component wrap mat-radio-button.
But i cannot use ngModel to binding and handle change event when select radio.
It used to work well in Angular 7 before.
Can anyone help me this issue?

Sorry if my english is not quite good,
Thank you so much :)

My code here:

**app.component.ts**

```
  _selection: any = 1;

  get selection() {
    return this._selection;
  }

  set selection(val: any) {
    this._selection = val;
  }

  onChange($event: any): void {
  }
```

**app.component.html:**

```
<my-radio-group [(ngModel)]="selection" (change)="onChange($event)">
  <br/>
  <my-radio-button [value]="1">Radio 1</my-radio-button>
  <br/>
  <my-radio-button [value]="2">Radio 2</my-radio-button>
  <br/>
  <my-radio-button [value]="3">Radio 3</my-radio-button>
  <br/>
  <my-radio-button [value]="4">Radio 4</my-radio-button>
</my-radio-group>
```

**my-radio-group.component.ts:**

```
export const MY_RADIO_GROUP_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR: any = {
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => MyRadioGroupComponent),
    multi: true
};

@Directive({
    selector: "my-radio-group",
    providers: [
        MY_RADIO_GROUP_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
        {provide: MatRadioGroup, useExisting: MyRadioGroupComponent}
    ]
})
export class MyRadioGroupComponent extends MatRadioGroup {

}
```

**my-radio-button.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: "my-radio-button",
    templateUrl: "./my-radio-button.component.html"
})
export class MyRadioButtonComponent {

    @Input() value: any;
    @Input() disabled: boolean | undefined;

}
```

**my-radio-button.component.html**

```
<mat-radio-button [value]="value" [disabled]="disabled">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</mat-radio-button>
```